# Calculating a Weight Enumerator Polynomial for a Linear Code

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, coding-theory

I'm studying the McEliece cryptosystem and the support splitting algorithm, and part of the algorithm involves calculating the weight enumerator polynomial for a linear code. Is there a specific algorithm for doing this, or is it something that has to be done just by looking at the generator matrix and enumerating all the linear combinations of the basis of the code?

Specifically, the code in question will be the hull of a Goppa code.

Comment: There are no simple algorithms (other than the brute-force enumeration you mentioned) that can be applied to all codes, but the weight enumerators of some codes can be found more easily by studying the code structure (or the dual code structure and applying the MacWilliams identities).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Later in the paper I'm reading they mention a $2^h$ time complexity ($h$ being the dimensional of the hull) so they must be assuming that. Do you know of any citation for this? If so, I'd add it to the Wikipedia article to save someone else some trouble.

Comment: If by $h$ you mean the dimension of the _dual_ code, then the MacWilliams-Sloane book is as good a reference as any.